# Python: Transform a CSV with one value per line to multiple values per line with first value as key

Tags: python, csv

I've been searching all over the interwebs for an answer to this one.
I have found answers pretty similar and close to this one but not similar enough for me to get the job done.

I've been trying to transform and/or re-order a CSV file that has a single value per line into a CSV with multiple values (comma separated) per line.

The input CSV looks something like this:

```
id,image
001,han.jpg
001,leia.jpg
001,chewie.jpg
002,stewie.jpg
002,meg.jpg
003,marty.jpg
003,doc_brown.jpg
003,biff.jpg
```

I need the output to be like this:

```
id,image
001,han.jpg,leia.jpg,chewie.jpg
002,stewie.jpg,meg.jpg
003,marty.jpg,doc-brown.jpg,biff.jpg
```

I know this might end up as an invalid CSV format but this isn't the final form of my CSV, this is just a step in between. There'll be more magic after this ;-).

I'd like a way to do this using Python for this will be part of a script I'm writing that's already written in Python.

I've been researching this for quite some time now so if anyone here is willing to help out that'd be awesome!

Comment: In general this is not a place to ask for complete solutions. Show what you have and someone might tell you how to do better. One hint: Assuming `var`contains one line of the cvs, `var.split(",")[0]` will give you the id, `var.split(",")[1]` the image. Now you need to research opening/reading files and how to loop through a file...

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to ask for a complete solution. I've done much reading (and hacking) before posting and I read a lot of stuff about 'Zip', 'Pandas' and the regular 'csv' package. I didn't know where to start I guess :-). I figured giving too much information would result in simpler solutions being discarded or ignored because of me being unclear. I'll be sure to include some snippets of my own next time I post here. Thanks for the pointers btw. This probably would've worked if I researched the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,

```
import csv
lines =[]
with open(inputFile,'rb') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f):
        lines.append(line)
def groupUp (lines):
    finalList = []
    for row in lines:
        for i,otherRow in enumerate(finalList):
            if row[0]==otherRow[0]:
                finalList[i] += row[1:]
                break
        else:
            finalList.append(row)
    return finalList

with open(newFile,'wb') as f:
    a = csv.writer(f)
    a.writerows(groupUp(lines))
```

Comment: Hi SuJaY, Thanks a lot for this! This is exactly what I needed! And you were also so fast in your response! I'll be contributing to Stack Overflow now that I'm a member. My specialty is mainly Front-end Development so I might be able to return the favor someday :-). I'm really happy to finally have a solution for this! Thanks again!

Comment: Hi , your welcome , But if this helps you , can you kindly up vote or mark as the best answer coz that can help me a lot and I can contribute more .

Comment: Hi @SuJaY I'd like to upvote you, I tried as soon as you posted this answer but I simply don't have enough reputation yet :(. I'm sorry. As soon as I gather enough reputation points I'll return to this question and upvote you. Perstonally I think it's extremely lame I'm not able to upvote comments on my self created question though..

Answer (score 0):

This code that will do what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

input = """id,image
001,han.jpg
001,leia.jpg
001,chewie.jpg
002,stewie.jpg
002,meg.jpg
003,marty.jpg
003,doc_brown.jpg
003,biff.jpg"""

# read the csv with pandas
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(input))

output = "id,image\n"
# group the dataset by id
for id_, data in df.groupby("id"):
    # that's a bit ugly, but it generates a line in the format you want
    output += "%d,%s\n" % (id_, ",".join(data["image"].values))

print output[:-1] # removes the last '\n'
```

As you said, the output is no longer a CSV file. Maybe another format would be more appropriate. A JSON for example might be a better fit for your problem.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks a lot for your fast response and your complete answer. I'm really amazed you were able to help me as fast as you did! This solution works perfectly! However the version by SuJaY uses the 'csv' package instead of Pandas. My script already includes the csv package, so for this reason I'm probably going to use his version instead. But I'm really thankful for your answer and it works just as well! This will be a great resource for others using pandas :-).